# Build errors with tikz externalize

Tags: tikz-external

I am putting together a manuscript for submission to a journal.  In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244879/am-i-properly-inserting-legends-in-groupplots-labels-multiply-defined) I had asked about some spurious warnings, but I can live with those.

As a final step before submitting my manuscript, I used \tikzexternalize to produce separate figures that I could submit alongside my main Latex document. On the first build everything is fine, but on subsequent builds I get 1 error per figure...but the output is just fine.  My concern is that the journal's submission guidelines say the text should compile without error, and they may not look past that.

I am using MikTex 2.9 and TeXnicCenter.  I have run `initexmf --edit-config-file=miktex\config\pdflatex.ini` and added `EnableWrite18=t`

This MWE recreates the issue for a single figure.  The data files can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/U34e8YvE) and [here](http://pastebin.com/i89yCk1a)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize



\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=2 by 1,
                             xlabels at=edge bottom,
                             ylabels at=edge left},
                xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate},
                view={0}{90},
                colorbar horizontal,
                colorbar to name=ContourColorbar,
                colormap/blackwhite,
                y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                    fixed,
                                    fixed zerofill,
                                    precision=2,
                                    /tikz/.cd},
                x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                    fixed,
                                    fixed zerofill,
                                    precision=0,
                                    /tikz/.cd}]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                     \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {ComeAndGoSurface.txt};
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                     \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PPResourcesSurface.txt};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ref{ContourColorbar}
    \caption{++Resources and Come and Go}
    \label{HeatMap}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error that is generated is

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
>   -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "MWE
>   -figure_crossref0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{MWE}\input{MWE}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'MWE-figure_crossr ef0' (expected one
>   of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
>   calls. For pdflatex, this is 'p dflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it
>   is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command
>   simply failed ? Error messages can be found in
>   'MWE-figure_crossref0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset
>   the picture.

The figure comes out just fine

[image]

For the record, and at the risk of cross-posting, this MWE also generates the warning I referred to in the linked question above.  That question remains unanswered, so if anyone can help me out there I'd appreciate it as well.  The warning is

> LaTeX Warning: Label `ContourColorbar' multiply defined.

I have seen a number of other posts with titles that sound similar, but the accepted answers have done nothing for me...multiple MikTex installations, bibtex issues, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: When submitting to journals I've always had to remove all tikz pictures and replace them with \includegraphics{tikzfigname} . Leaving in the tikz stuff just causes errors when using the journal's Latex (even if it doesn't on my computer).

Comment: can you show us the content of `MWE-figure_crossref0.log`? It should contain the root cause of the failure.

Comment: With high probability, this issue is the one described in the TikZ manual, "50.4.1 Support for Labels and References In External Files" : these external references need extra steps during the externalization (described in that section)

Comment: Forgive my naivety...it was probably too optimistic of me to stop reading at 3.2.6 in the pgfplots manual !  I will go find the reference you provided and see if I can figure it out....

Comment: I will add the contents of the log file to the original question.

Comment: Scratch that...too long.  Log file contents are [here](http://pastebin.com/PCSr9Dyc)

Comment: @Vermilion -- I figured I would just go with that approach, but that creates a new problem.  Where I have a groupplot with a single common legend, I do that with legend to name (as I mentioned in the question I linked to) and then \ref it after the figure.  Those legends do not get included in the external pdf.  So if I go the \includegraphics route none of my groupplots have legends now.  Incredibly frustrating...this is the only thing between me and submission right now.

Comment: The TikZ manual 50.4.1 offers this advice if there is a \ref inside of externalized graphics: "Thus: if you have \ref inside of external graphics, consider using mode=list and make or copy-paste the system call for the image(s) and issue it manually."  I'm afraid I'm out of my depth here.  As I mentioned, I thought I would simply take the externalized graphics and \includegraphics them, but that doesn't provide for my groupplot legends....